# How do I perform a reverse history search in ZSH's vi-mode?

Tags: zsh, command-history, vi-mode

I use `vim` for essentially all my editing needs, so I decided to once again try vi-mode for my shell (currently ZSH w/ oh-my-zsh on OS X), but I find myself trying (and failing) to use `Ctrl-R` constantly. What's the equivalent key-binding? And for future reference, how would I figure this out myself? I'm pretty sure I could use `bind -P` in bash.

Comment: According to 'man zshzle', history-incremental-search-backward is not bound in Vi modes (vicmd, viins) by default.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can run `bindkey` with no arguments to get a list of existing bindings, eg:

```
# Enter vi mode
chopper:~> bindkey -v

# Search for history key bindings
chopper:~> bindkey | fgrep history
"^[OA" up-line-or-history
"^[OB" down-line-or-history
"^[[A" up-line-or-history
"^[[B" down-line-or-history
```

In emacs mode, the binding you want is `history-incremental-search-backward`, but that is not bound by default in vi mode. To bind Ctrl-R yourself, you can run this command, or add it to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
bindkey "^R" history-incremental-search-backward
```

The `zshzle` manpage (`man zshzle`) has more information on zsh's line editor, bindkey, and emacs/vi modes.

Comment: Thanks, particularly for `zshzle`. That is quite informative and useful.

Comment: I love you. Seriously. After upgrading to OSX El Capitan reverse search was gone and I missed it more than everything else in my daily workflow.

Comment: `esc` `/` seems like the right answer however, not so much just rebinding one emacs mode keybinding into vi mode.

Answer (score 67):

This is an ancient question, but the only (and accepted) answer basically tells one how to transplant the “emacs-like” `history-incremental-search-backward` to vi mode.  Whilst this is perfectly doable and may be the right solution for you, it’s a little strange that no one has mentioned the “vi way” of searching history.

vi mode in zsh supports searching history using the standard vi/vim keys:  `/` and `?`, both available in command mode.  (Hit `<Esc>` to switch from insert to command mode, just like in vi or vim.)

Their sense is reversed, though:  Since you usually want to search your shell’s history in reverse, `/` does a reverse search whereas `?` does a forward search.

Once the first hit is displayed, you can (just like in vi/vim) use `n` to continue finding more hits in the same direction, or `N` to reverse the direction of the search.

The relevant default keybindings in the `vicmd` keymap are:

```
"/" vi-history-search-backward
"?" vi-history-search-forward
"n" vi-repeat-search
"N" vi-rev-repeat-search
```

Comment: It's also good to use `"^P" history-beginning-search-backward` and `"^N" history-beginning-search-forward` for vim-like autocompletion (you start typing, then press `ctrl+p` or `ctrl+n`).

Comment: For me, `?` brings up `bck-i-search`, which is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @wjv the advantage of history-incremental-search-backward is that is supports glob patterns. The default `/` or `?' doesnt: https://coderwall.com/p/-jvcag/zsh-reverse-history-search-with-regex

Comment: @alpha_989 The blog post you reference is incorrect. It may be that the author has some zsh “framework” installed that overloads the `^R` keybinding. The only “regex-like” character supported by both `history-search-backward` and `history-incremental-search-backward` is `^`, to anchor the search string to the start of the line. The real power of `history-incremental-search-backward` is that it does an incremental search, as its name suggests. I can imagine that one might want to bind it in the `vicmd` keymap for that reason.

Comment: @wjv, you are right.. I should have written `history-incremental-pattern-search-backward`, not `history-incremental-search-backward`. `history-incremental-pattern-search-backwards` maybe a widget.. but I think it comes installed by default in zsh. It supports `glob` patterns not `regex` as you correctly pointed out: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators. There is indeed a mistake in the post..

Comment: Are you aware of any method to use `extended regex` search through zsh history? The only method I can think of is to use `vim-8`s term mode.. to search through zsh history..using `vim-regex`. I find the `ctrl-R` and `/` to be rather limited, since I work fully in the terminal.

Comment: I think this answer is superior to the currently accepted answer because it points out the n, N bindings. This is intuitive to a vi user, but also nonintuitive in a way because I had no idea it was there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following at the bottom of `~/.zshrc`, then `source ~/.zshrc`

```bash
bindkey -M vicmd '/' history-incremental-search-backward
```